R: factor(x, levels, labels) returns unexpected <NA>
I'm not sure how else to describe this problem. I hope someone knows of this issue already.
Reprex:
t_fac <- factor(c("A", "A"))
t_lev <- factor(c("B", "C"))
t_lab <- c(1, 1)

factor(t_fac, levels = t_lev, labels = t_lab)

Returns:
[1] <NA> <NA>
Levels: 1

Where I would expect:
[1] 1 1
Levels: 1

How to get expected result? Any ideas are welcome.

Could you elaborate a bit on your specific use? Your t_fac ("A") is not reflected in the levels ("B", "C"), so returns NA since factor cant find the level "A" in the user-specified levels. Your labels are also length = 2, but you only have one level ("A"). If you run factor(t_fac, labels = 1) it gives what you want in this SO question, but my sense is thats not generalizable to what you want more broadly in your application

Reading from the help page for factor, levels is "an optional vector of the unique values (as character strings) that x might have taken". You have the value "A" in your data vector (t_fac), but you include only "B" and "C" as levels.
I think you can adjust this simply by including "A" as a possible level:
t_fac <- c("A", "A")
t_lev <- c("A", "B") # "A" needs to be here
t_lab <- c(1, 1)

factor(t_fac, levels = t_lev, labels = t_lab)

[1] 1 1
Levels: 1

If you want to have "A", "B", and "C" as possible levels, you will need to add a 1 in the labels vector:
t_fac <- c("A", "A")
t_lev <- c("A", "B", "C")
t_lab <- c(1, 1, 1)

factor(t_fac, levels = t_lev, labels = t_lab)


Do you mean this?
> factor(t_fac, labels = unique(t_lab))
[1] 1 1
Levels: 1

